# Array Out of bounds and Converting list<Object> to string[]

Tags: java, arrays, spring-boot

Hi I am trying to read all the data in my array and it produces the `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` and I think I need to decrement it but don't know how using for each loop can anyone help me here is the code thanks

```
@PostMapping(path = "/createBooking/{location}")
public ResponseEntity<String> create(@PathVariable(value = "location") String location,
        @Validated @RequestBody Booking book) {
    book.setStatus("reserved");
    book.setBookingCode(generatedString);

    bookingRepository.save(book);

    MimeMessage message = sender.createMimeMessage();
    MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        String[] array = new String[book.getAtt().size()];
        int index = array.length - 1;
        for (Object value : book.getAtt()) {
            array[index--] = String.valueOf( value );
        }
        helper.setTo(array[index]);
        sb.append("Agenda:" + " " + book.getBookingDesc()).append(System.lineSeparator());
        sb.append("When:" +  " " + book.getDateBooked() + " " + book.getStartTime() + " " + "To" + " " + book.getEndTime())
                .append(System.lineSeparator());
        sb.append("Where:" + " " + location).append(System.lineSeparator());
        sb.append("By:" + " " + book.getBookedUser()).append(System.lineSeparator());
        sb.append("Booking code:" + " " + generatedString);
        helper.setText(sb.toString());
        helper.setSubject("Meeting");
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Error while sending mail ..", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    sender.send(message);

    return new ResponseEntity<>("Inputs have been saved", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

would also appreciate if you can tell if I'm doing it right too thanks

EDIT: here is the trace error
EDIT: I added the whole class

```
"trace": "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 2\r\n\tat com.example.rba.controller.Controller.create(Controller.java:79)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest
```

Comment: What you want to do here, helper.setTo(array[index]);
If you want to add the first element from the list, simply do helper.setTo(book.getAtt().get(0))

Comment: helper.setTo(array[index]); at this point index=-1 so you are getting Index -1 out of bounds.

Comment: @Code_Mode But I want to add the whole data of the array to setTo not just the first element for example I have 2 data in the array I want those 2 data to be at setTo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception will be at:

```
helper.setTo(array[index]);
```

Your loop iteration will work like this:
1st Iteration: Value is stored at last index (n) and then index = n-1
2nd Iteration: Value is stored at n-1 index, and index = n-2
....
Last Iteration: Value is stored at 0 index, and n becomes -1.

Now, when you try setting helper to array[-1], it will give you ArrayIndexOutOfBound.

*If you found this helpful, please don't forget to mark this as an answer.*

Comment: so what do you suggest I put instead on setTo(); ?

Answer (score 1):

```
    You can do this 

String[] array = new String[book.getAtt().size()];
                int index = array.length-1;
                for (Object value : book.getAtt()) {
                    array[index] = String.valueOf( value );
                    index--;
                }
```

Comment: I added the trace and the whole class

Answer (score 1):

Array indexing starts with o so `array.length` would result in `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`. You can initialize index to 0 and use as below,

```
   int index = 0;
    for (Object value : book.getAtt()) {
       array[index++] = String.valueOf( value );
    }
```

Or if want to insert from end,

```
int index = array.length-1;
for (Object value : book.getAtt()) {
       array[index--] = String.valueOf( value );
}
```

If you just want to set the first element from the list in `helper.setTo(array[index]);`
no need to create separate array, simply do `helper.setTo(book.getAtt().get(0))`

Comment: still same error I added the trace and the whole class

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved I just moved the helper.setTo(array[index]); inside the loop and the error is gone but have a new error but different topic thank you